# Is it possible to install Pywin32 on windows 8?

Tags: python, windows, windows-8, python-2.7, pywin32

I´ve already tried many times , but I think is not possible to install pywin32 on windows 8. I always get the same error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 612, in <module>
File "<string>", line 322, in install
File "<string>", line 160, in LoadSystemModule
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I´ve no problem installing it on any other windows version.

Is it possible ? Does anyone got it working ?

Comment: which error that you get ?

Comment: I´ve corrected the question with error

Comment: also tell the command you entered (or icon clicked) that got the error, and give a link to the file you were trying to install

Comment: I tried pywin32-217.win32-py2.6 , pywin32-218.win32-py2.6 and pywin32-214.win32-py2.6.
I am using python2.6 and all other modules are ok (pygame, wxpython, PIL, Setuptools, etc..)

Comment: It works well for me with python 3.3.2 and pywin32-218.win32-py3.3 on windows 8

Answer (score 0):

It gives me an error but worked with version pywin32-214.win32-py2.6. Thanks.